# Running Linux's terminal commands from C# Mono application

Tags: c#, bash, process, mono, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to execute `shutter` (app for screenshots) as a `Process` class from C# Mono application in Ubuntu 16.04. I'm using the code which is located in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506985/c-opening-the-terminal-process-and-pass-commands).

Unfortunately I'm getting error `Command not found`. It works for standard commands like `ls, pwd ...`. I realized that when I do `cd /` I see different folders and files(like `app`, `.flatpak` etc.) than, let's say, "local" and hence bash can't find `shutter` because it's not there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried either adding Shutter to the dir of the app or changing to the working dir to the one where Shutter is sitting?

Comment: I've tried changing the working dir (/usr/bin/) - and I saw that there were less apps than I have local - no shutter.
I didn't try adding Shutter to the dir of the app - can you explain it a bit ?

Comment: Is `shutter` in your `PATH`?

Comment: locally, yes, but when I show `PATH` inside my C# mono app, it has only one entry (at this moment can't provide it)

Comment: When I put shutter files inside folder `bin/debug`, my app can see it, but when I run it `./shutter` there is error: `/usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter`, so there is no perl... is it like mono runs programs in it's own environment?

Answer (score 0):

Instead `shutter' use this:

`export SHUTTER=$(which shutter); $SHUTTER`

`which shutter` will return full path of `shutter` app

Comment: My app doesn't see shutter installed from within `Process`